# Returns 404 status code even though I am given the correct data

Tags: services

I'm using Drupal Services to get JSON for an Angular app. Everything works fine on my local (`Mac OX 10.10, Apache/2.4.9`), but I've just deployed to a DigitalOcean instance (`Ubuntu 14.04, Apache/2.4.7`) and that's where I'm getting the 404 statuses (even though the request Response is fine). I'm not seeing any errors in my `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

I'm guessing there's maybe a configuration difference between my local and the DigitalOcean instance? But I don't know what it would be.

Here's my XHR traffic:

[image]

Comment: Do you have [clean urls](https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls) enabled on the deployment environment?

Comment: Yep. At first they weren't working, but it was because I didn't have AllowOveride All set and my .htaccess file wasn't getting read.